# c++ map finding value and associated key

Tags: c++, templates, dictionary, stl, client-server

I develop one program in c++ in which i have to find key in stl map by using values.
But values assigned to key is the 5 tuples (srcip,port,destip,port,srcno)

Now i want to check in map whether there is key assosiated with values.
I am trying something like this.

But its showing error like 
wrong number of template argument.
Note(In my program in pair key->Value) value consist of tuple of 5 variable.

```
template<class T>
struct map_data_compare : public std::binary_function<typename T::value_type,typename T::mapped_type,bool>
{
public:
bool operator() (typename T::value_type &pair,typename T::mapped_type i)
{
return pair.second == i;
}
}


class Values
{
private:
std::string C_addr;
int C_port;
std::string S_addr;
int S_port;
int C_ID;

public:
Values(std::string,int,std::string,int,int);
void printValues();
};


Values :: Values(std::string Caddr,int Cport,std::string Saddr,int Sport,int Cid)
{
C_addr=Caddr;
C_port=Cport;
S_addr=Saddr;
S_port=Sport;
C_ID=Cid;
}

void Values::printValues()
{
cout << C_addr<<":" <<C_port<<":" << S_addr <<":" <<S_port << ":"<<C_ID  <<endl;
}



//In main

    {

    typedef std::map<int, Values> itemsType;
    itemsType items;


    Values connection (inet_ntoa(clientaddr.sin_addr),ntohs(clientaddr.sin_port),inet_ntoa(servaddr.sin_addr),ntohs(servaddr.sin_port),clientID);



    std::map<std::int,Values>::iterator it = std::find_if( items.begin(), items.end(), std::bind2nd(map_data_compare<itemsType>(),connection));

    if ( it != items.end() )
    {
    assert( connection == it->second);
    std::cout << "Found index:" << it->first << " for values:" << it->second << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
    std::cout << "Did not find index for values:" << connection <<endl;
    }
```

Comment: Why don't you use your defined comparator to sort the map in the first place, rather than sorting using the default one and then using your own comparator again.

Comment: will u please explain it by code.

Comment: It's showing error, hey?  You could post the exact message and mark the line of code it fails on.  Anyway, do you have a working operator== for Value?  Seems simpler to me to pass connection to the map_data_compare constructor and have it stored, rather than binding, but either way's ok....

Comment: yaa it supporting == operator. and error is-wrong number of template arguments (1, should be 4) /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.6/../../../../include/c++/4.4.6/bits/stl_ma‌​p.h:86: error: provided for ‘template<class _Key, class _Tp, class _Compare, class _Alloc> class std::map.  I edited code here.

Comment: And which line's 86?  We shouldn't have to grope around when you have relevant information....

Answer (score 0):

> I develop one program in c++ in which i have to find key in stl map by using values.

That's not what maps are meant for. If you need that kind of access, I recommend [Boost.Bimap](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/bimap/doc/html/index.html)

Comment: I cant use Boost.Bitmap

Comment: Then just use two maps, one from A to B, and one from B to A, and keep them in sync.

Answer (score 0):

If the 'key' must be unique, maybe you can try combine the key and value into a `std::pair` and push them into `std::set`.

Otherwise you should set your key as value and value as key since you seems mainly use your original value as what we treat to a "key". Then you could use the built-in `map::find()` function